# I can't save my emission pass

Tags: render-passes

I'm working on a big project in blender 2.82, I open and close it a lot, do renders.

My compositing setup uses the emission pass, but every time I close the file and reopen it, the emission pass becomes unchecked and if I forget to re-enable it, my renders are washed out.
It's pretty annoying to have to check it again every single time, and that doesn't happen with the other passes.

If you have any idea where this might come from, thank you

Comment: tested at same blender version, emission pass stay checked after file reopen.
may be some scripts mess it up?
as the last resort try factory startup..